# why does the class offset-xs-* not move my div in bootstrap 4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have write this html:

```
  <h2>Column Offsetting</h2>
  <div style="max-width: 1200px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 10px;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px;">
        <div class="col-12 offset-xs-2 col-md-4 thumb"></div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4 thumb"></div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4 thumb"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And I don't understand why the first div (with ) does not offset.
I have replace `offset-xs-2` with `offset-md-2` and it working just fine for medium screen.

Is the bootstrap class offset-* only working with medium screen ?

**Actual result**:[image: Screen capture actual result]

**Expectation**:[image: Screen capture expectation]

Here is a like to a codesandbox: [The link](https://codesandbox.io/s/bootstrap-offsetting-not-working-for-xs-9hjlp?file=/index.html)

Comment: Add two screenshot your expected result both small and medium devices. For clarify this question.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code:

```html
    <h2>Column Offsetting</h2>
    <div style="max-width: 1200px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 10px;">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                <div class="col-xs-12 offset-md-2 col-md-4 thumb"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 thumb"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 thumb"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Actually xs works on small screens. With xs, reduce your browser window and see its effect. Medium works with medium size screen. Bea cause you haven't specified large and extra large here, medium works for them also.
Think this way, bootstrap searches for the style which suits best in the current browser window.

When we watch page with size of monitor, it searches style in the order extra large > large > medium > small > extra small. When we watch page on mobile, it searches style in the order extra small > small > medium > large > extra large.

To know about different sizes check this out: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/overview/

But basically you can imagine this way:

- Extra Small - anything smaller than mobile screen
- Small - mobile screen
- Medium - small tablet screen
- Large - big tablet screen
- Extra Large - monitor screen

Comment: When I resize the browser windows the div size change but the offset of the first one doesn't appear.

Comment: I don't understand why the order as importance ?

Comment: Think this way, a desktop site would better visible on mobile or tablet or desktop? On the other hand, a mobile site would better visible on desktop or tablet or mobile? They must load styles which is more closer to device on which we are using this site. So mobile site search for mobile styles if not found search for tablet styles and if that also not found load desktop style as last resort. Same thing happen when we view site on desktop but in reverse order.

Comment: I still do not understand. You are saying that my viewport is not small enough to get the offset effect even though the div size change ?

Comment: Exactly. Watch offset-xs on mobile. You will see the effect

Comment: There is a Chrome extension called **Resolution Test**. Use it to view your page in different mobile and tablet sizes on your computer.

Comment: Hope I helped you. Tick and Up-vote if you think I solved your doubts. Happy Coding :)

Comment: I have added a custom size of 200X800 but and resize the windows but the offset still does not work. Sorry xD

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get the offset working only for the xs screens

```
  <h2>Column Offsetting</h2>
  <div style="max-width: 1200px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 10px;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px;">
        <div class="col-1 offset-2 offset-sm-0 col-md-4 thumb"></div>
        <div class="col-1 col-md-4 thumb"></div>
        <div class="col-1 col-md-4 thumb"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I added `offset-2` to add an offset to the first div for all screen and then I add `offset-sm-0` to remove the offset on all the other screen size.